# Whilst having my INT0 initialized as digital Input, it still gives out 2.8V which makes the Button don't really making a change

Tags: c, interrupt, pic, xc8

My Problem is that I have a digital Input initialized on PORTB.0. On that Pin I have a button and a 100k Pull-down Resistor. When I run my Pic with literally nothing ( void main() {while(1){}} ) the Voltage level on this pin works as I want it to (0 to 3.3V). But after I test my programm and initialize as shown in the Code below, it's range goes from 2.8 to 3.3V.

I am using a PIC18LF2520 for my graduation work. I am Programming in MPlab V5.10 with the XC8 1.45 Compiler. I just want an Interrupt for my Button which lies on the RB0 Pin of the uP. The initialisations I made will be shown on the Code down below. I already worked a lot with this particular PIC, but I have never had such an Error before.

```
void main() {

    init();

    while(1) {    
        /*
        if(isEXT0Set()) {   //If the Button gets pushed
            EXT0Int();      //Interrupt Function call
        }
        */
    }    
}

void init() {

   //PORT Definitions

    TRISA = 0x00;
    TRISB = 0xC3;
    TRISC = 0x00;

    //Oscillator Settings

    OSCCON = 0x7F;  //8Mhz; Internal Oscillator; INTOSC stable

    //Interrupt Settings

    INTCON = 0xF0;  //Global Enable; Peripherals Enable; TMR0 Enable; INT0 Enable
    INTCON2 = 0x64; //INT0 rising Edge; INT1 rising Edge; TMR0 High Priority
    INTCON3 = 0x08; //INT1 Enable
    ADCON1 = 0x0F; //set all Inputs to Digital ones.

    //Timer Settings

    T0CON = 0x86;   //16-Bit; LtoH; 1/128
    T1CON = 0x31;   //2 8-Bit; FOSC/4; 1/8
    T2CON = 0x07;   //Postscaler 1/1; Prescaler 1/16;

    TMR0H = 0xE1;   //Setting TMR0 to 1 Second
    TMR0L = 0x7B;  

    TMR1IE = 1;
    TMR2IE = 0;
}
```

I expect that when I push the button that INt0IF will be set, but that doesn't happen. I testes it on the Hardware, the result is decribed up above. I hope someone sees what I missed. Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: Where is your ISR?

Comment: Use 10k for pull resistors.

Answer (score 1):

PIC controller has internal pull-up resistors on PORTB and usually, they're much less than 100kOhm. You can turn all of them just changing INTCON2 initialization to:

```
INTCON2 = 0xE4;
```